# Apprtc - Websocket connection failed

Tags: google-app-engine, apprtc

I have installed and configured `AppRTC`, `Collider`, turn-server successfully.
But I am facing an issue of `Websocket` Error. Google chrome console errors are as follows:

```
Initializing; server= undefined.
apprtc.debug.js:5583 1.413: Initializing; room=undefined.
apprtc.debug.js:5583 5.209: Opening signaling channel.
apprtc.debug.js:5583 5.390: Got access to local media with mediaConstraints:
'{"audio":true,"video":{"optional":[{"minWidth":"1280"},{"minHeight":"720"}],"mandatory":{}}}'
apprtc.debug.js:5583 5.390: User has granted access to local media.
apprtc.debug.js:5583 5.391: Attaching local stream.
apprtc.debug.js:5092 WebSocket connection to 'wss://104.198.4.111:8089/ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(anonymous) @ apprtc.debug.js:5092
apprtc.debug.js:5583 5.578: WebSocket open error: WebSocket error.
apprtc.debug.js:5583 5.584: WebSocket register error: WebSocket error.
apprtc.debug.js:5583 5.636: Joined the room.
```

Following is the screenshot of WebSocket error, which I am facing

[image]

`Collider` and `AppRTC` are on Google VM instance and I have used my own turn-server which has been setup on `AWS EC2` instance.
Please help me to resolve this issue.
Is there any setting in `Google APP engine`, where I deployed an APP?

Advanced help would be appreciated !

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Comment: In my project, we have found the same issues, we already implemented STUN and TURN servers successfully in Linux and Windows servers. but for Signalling server we got above issues, please share the updates if you found any..!